# Utilidad de operador " ~ " en CSS

Tags: css, html5, css3, scss

Tengo una duda sobre este operador **`~`** el cual vi que se utilizaba como una especie de selector en **CSS**.
Lo vi en un tutorial en el cual el instructor utiliza dicho operador junto con la clase `:checked` de un elemento input de tipo *radio button*, tal que asi:

```
input:cheked ~ div{
     background-color: red;
}
```

en realidad no le cambia el color pero es solo demostrar como lo utiliza.
Si alguien sabe el funcionamiento me seria de ayuda porque en otras circunstancias no me funciono, nose si sera por culpa de la herencia o que.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: y la pregunta cual es?

Comment: para que se utiliza, porque no comprendo q funcion cumple dicho selector, porque lo intente usar en otras circunstancias y no me funciono

Comment: Selecciona cualquier div precedido por un input radio o checkbox que esta marcado checked

Comment: Una lista de [Selectores CSS](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/css3/chuleta-selectores-css3.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este operador `~` sirve para identificar a aquellos elementos que estan precedidos por otro del DOM, es decir

Si yo coloco esto

```
div ~ p
```

Lo que le estoy diciendo es que aplique estilos a todos los elementos `p` que tienen **antes** de ellos un `<div> </div>`

*Ojo*

El elemento div en el ejemplo anterior debe estar justo antes del elemento `p`

Imagina este ejemplo

```
<p>
  <a href="">Uno</a>
  <a href="">Dos</a>
</p>
  <div> </div>
    <p>Hola Mundo</p>
```

Del código anterior yo solo quiero aplicarle estilos de color rojo a aquellos párrafos `p` que tengan antes un `div`

Entonces mi código CSS debe quedar del modo siguiente

```
div ~ p{
      color: red;
    }
```

Leyendolo de izquierda a derecha se interpreta así

> Selecciona todos las etiquetas p, que antes de ellas tengan un div y a esos párrafos > `p` aplicales un color de letra rojo

Cuyo resultado será así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EJEMPLO**

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <style>
        div ~ p{
          color: red;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>
      <a href="">Uno</a>
      <a href="">Dos</a>
    </p>
      <div> </div>
        <p>Hola Mundo</p>
     
    </body>
    </html>
```

Entonces para tu pregunta es:

> Aplicar un color de fondo rojo para todo div que se encuentre
>   precedido o que antes de el exista un `input` de tipo radio y que se
>   encuentre como `checked` ignorando a los que no cumplan esa condición

Comment: Ahhhhh, ahora comprendo, gracias, pero antes, si yo quisiera ocurriese algo en un div cuando se cumpla el evento `:checked`, deberia optar por **obviar** el operador " ~ "?
De forma que me quede de la siguiente manera ?:
´`nput:checked div{ color: red }`

Comment: al menos a como se las cosas @Diego en esa situación debería ser así mas o menos `input[type="radio"]:checked + div{
      color: red;
    }` pues con ayuda del signo `+` indicas que se afecten todos los elementos que estan **justo** después de un input type radio y que esta checked

Comment: Ahora si, muchas gracias shadow

Comment: *"El elemento div en el ejemplo anterior debe estar justo antes del elemento p"* Eso sería en el caso de usar el operador `+` que selecciona hermanos adyacentes, con `~` selecciona a todos los hermanos siempre vayan después

Answer (score 2):

Es un selector parecido al `+` pero en vez de que sólo tome el primer elemento encontrado, este va a tomar todos los elementos.

Por ejemplo: `h2 + p` seleccionará en rojo la primera etiqueta `<p>` que encuentre.

```css
h2 + p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>Título</h2>
<p>Párrafo 1</p>
<p>Párrafo 2</p>
<p>Párrafo 3</p>
```

Mientras que con el selector `~` seleccionará todos los elementos encontrados.

```css
h2 ~ p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2>Título</h2>
<p>Párrafo 1</p>
<p>Párrafo 2</p>
<p>Párrafo 3</p>
```

---

Para más información de los selectores CSS te recomiendo que le des una mirada a [Los 30 selectores CSS que debes memorizar](https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) que tiene todas la información de los selectores CSS. Me sirvió mucho cuando comencé.